# How to structure jQuery for nunjucks and node js application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, nunjucks

I am using nunjucks and jquery for single page interactions. The server side code is running on top of node.js and express.js.

Currenly, I have a views folder I have structured my views file as follows:

-views
---templates
----base
----layout
---pages
----login
----register

For the single page jQuery interaction, I have used nunjucks and embedded the corressponding jquery in the scripts tags.

For login.njk, I have used  tags and included the corresponding page at the bottom. Should I go with this approach or should create a js folder and include scrip src for the corresponding page.

Are there any better approaches?